# Transmit data using sound and recover it on the other PC in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, digital, transmission, modulation

I want to transmit data from a PC to another PC using sound. I am trying PSK Modulation but when I play sound of my output signal and record it on the other one, It is very distorted and I can't even notice the phase changes. Am I missing something?

For further details, I want to make a wireless calculator that takes input on a computer and then transmits it using sound waves to the other PC where the results are calculated and the results are transmitted back.

Comment: what happens if you 'save' your audio as a signal, and 'load' it again from matlab? if you still get the artifacts, then it has nothing to do with how the sound is transmitted, and you know your problem is with how you're processing it.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou points in the right direction, verify your system step by step. Another approach would be to transmit a sine wave in the audible range. Can you hear it? Is it distorted? How does the plot look like?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou  I saved the output signal as audio and re-loaded it which resulted in the same result as was transmitted/saved which means that my transmitter is okay and I was able to decode that audio file to the data that I transmitted using PSK